# ssrs 2008 r2 export to csv and excel

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

In an SSRS 2008 r2, I am going to have some selected colunmns set as invisibile while the ssrs 2008 r2 report is running. However when the report is exported only to excel and csv files, I want those invisible columns to be included in the export. Thus can you tell me and or show me in code how to add the selected invisible columns to only the CSV and excel exports?

Answer (score 3):

If you right click on the column and select 'Column Visibility...' and select 'Show or hide based on an expression' and enter the following code:

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL" or Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV",false,true)
```

This should only display the column when it is exported to Excel or as a CSV.

Also make sure you have the DataElementOutput property set to 'Auto' as if it is set to 'NoOutput' it will not export to .CSV

Comment: The code works for exporting to excel. However the code does not work for for CSV file export. Thus can you tell me how to export for comma delimited fgiles?

Comment: @user1816979 When the column is selected, in the Properties window, have a look for the 'DataElementOutput' property. If this is set to 'NoOutput' this will not output the data to the .CSV based on the conditional statement. That property value is used to exclude columns from export. There is a good explanation of that property on this [site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bimusings/archive/2007/02/07/reporting-services-why-aren-t-all-my-report-columns-exporting-to-csv-and-or-xml.aspx). I have it set to auto and it is working for me.

Comment: You may want to check the value of `Globals!RenderFormat.Name` when exporting to Excel. I've found that it's sometimes *not* `EXCEL`, but rather `EXCELOPENXML`.